# Testing XSRF Attacks through HTML form & direct URL

Tags: html, url, csrf

I have a web application, on which we currently implement XSRF protection.
From what I gather, XSRF attacks work this way:

- the attacker finds out how the client communicates with the server of
  the web application, i.e. how its HTTP requests are formatted
- the attacker rewrites (forges) a http request that would order the
  server    to do what the attacker wants
- all the attacker now lacks is an authentification on the server
- the attacker tricks people into    loading a webpage that sends his
  forged request. Out of the people    who get tricked, those who
  happen to be currently logged in the    application will unwillingly
  provide the forged request with the    credentials it needs to be executed
  by the server.

To test our website, I looked at the POST HTTP requests the client sends to the server to give it orders (using F12 in Internet Explorer), and forged one myself.
It looks like this:

```
https://mywebsite/Camp.aspx?
EventTarget=SaveButton
&TargetField=I+am+the+king+of+the+world
```

First line is the URL seen in the browser (minus the "?"), second line is the action to be executed by the server, 3rd line is the field I want to update.

Then I logged on the website and tested my forged request in 2 ways:

A) I simply open a new tab in the browser, paste the forged URL above and click enter
(tested with IE and Chrome)

B) I open in another tab a page with content:

```
<html xmlns="http_www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="https://mywebsite/Camp.aspx">
            <input type="hidden" name="EventTarget" value="SaveButton">
            <input type="hidden" name="TargetField" value="I+am+the+king+of+the+world">
        </form>
        <script>
            document.forms[0].submit();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

(tested with methods GET and POST)

I would expect both tests to be identical but to my surprise:

- test A opens the target page on the website and actually updates the
  target field
- test B opens the target page on the website but does not    update
  the target field

I have 2 questions:

1. Why do test A and test B bring different results?
2. Test B definitely is a valid CSRF Attack Test (even though an
   attacker would rather want to do the action without opening the
   page), is Test A also valid?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the Problem myself.
I had obviously posted a simplified version of the request. The real request contained signs that need to be URL-encoded. Here it was the sign "$", which encodes in URL as "%24".

So if the direct URL is

```
https://mywebsite/Camp.aspx?
EventTarget=abc%24def
```

then the corresponding HTML form should be

```
<html xmlns="http_www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="https://mywebsite/Camp.aspx">
            <input type="hidden" name="EventTarget" value="abc$def">
        </form>
        <script>
            document.forms[0].submit();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```